# Installing packages on a Mac using pip installer

Tags: python, pandas, macos, numpy, installation

I am in need of some serious help. It started when I was trying to install pandas using pip in my terminal, when I kept getting a massive error that would say the computer failed to build wheels for `numpy`.

I then uninstalled `numpy` to see if possibly a refresh would change this, and now when I try to install `numpy` I get this error-

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have tried using pip, pip3, pip 3.8 and none work for anything. I have a brand new lap top and have python 3.9 and 2.7 installed so I have literally no clue what I could have messed up because I have barely done anything with it.

Please help if you can, I am losing my mind!

p.s. I have the M1 processor if that changes anything

Comment: Faced this issue some months back. Do not really remember what I did. I would suggest two things:
1) User brew to install it.
If (1) doesn't work, 2) Install python 3.8 and then install numpy. There are issues on the web where users face this problem with 3.9.

Comment: Please provide the command and entire error message

Comment: Mac has both Python and Python3 right?  so yea, try `python3 -m pip install numpy`